# Curl: Fix CURL (51) SSL error: no alternative certificate subject name matches

Tags: ssl, curl, https

I am new to CURL world, coming from Windows + .NET domain.

Trying to access Rest API for basic authentication at http://www.evercam.io/docs/api/v1/authentication.

```
curl -X GET https://api.evercam.io/v1/... \
-u {username}
```

Don't know how to use this command on windows command prompt after having CURL setup successfully. Tested CURL as follows:

```
C:\>curl --version
curl 7.33.0 (x86_64-pc-win32) libcurl/7.33.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8y zlib/1.2.8 libssh2/1.4.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps pop3 pop3s rtsp scp s
ftp smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS GSS-Negotiate Largefile NTLM SSL SSPI libz
```

Now i am ending with this

```
C:\>curl -u myuser:mypassword -X GET https://api.evercam.io/v1/
curl: (51) SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'api.evercam.io'
```

How can I fix this SSL issue 51 error ?

Answer (score 156, accepted):

It usually happens when the certificate does not match with the host name.

The solution would be to contact the host and ask it to fix its certificate.
Otherwise you can turn off cURL's verification of the certificate, use the `-k` (or `--insecure`) option.
Please note that as the option said, it is *insecure*. You shouldn't use this option because it allows man-in-the-middle attacks and defeats the purpose of HTTPS.

More can be found in here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

Comment: Answers telling to turn the check off, should also highlight what the consequences are. This is dangerous!

Comment: Thing I figured was subject name on cert was `*.my-domain.com` which did not apply to `dev.subdomain.my-domain.com`. But works fine for `dev-subdomain.my-domain.com`. So to make multiple sub-domain work maybe you need what this article says - https://www.sslshopper.com/article-ssl-certificates-for-multi-level-subdomains.html

Comment: @prayagupa You should make yours the answer. The accepted answer is for inexperienced developers that don't yet understand end to end implications of things.

Answer (score 97):

Editor's note: this is a very dangerous approach, if you are using a version of PHP old enough to use it. It opens your code to man-in-the-middle attacks and removes one of the primary purposes of an encrypted connection. The ability to do this has been removed from modern versions of PHP because it is so dangerous. The only reason this has been upvoted 70 time is because people are lazy. DO NOT DO THIS.

---

I know it's a (very) old question and it's about command line, but when I searched Google for "SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name", this was the first hit.

It took me a good while to figure out the answer so hope this saves someone a lot of time! 
In PHP add this to your cUrl setopts:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
```

p.s: this should be a temporary solution. Since this is a certificate error, best thing is to have the certificate fixed ofcourse!

Comment: Well, this came up in my google search for the problem I was having in PHP, so this was helpful for me.

Comment: I did the same search and I am glad to have your answer here. Thanks!

Comment: `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` was enough in my case

Comment: Thanks useful for testing purposes if you dont have your certificates up yet.

Answer (score 22):

The common name in the certicate for `api.evercam.io` is for `*.herokuapp.com` and there are no alternative subject names in the certificate. This means, that the certificate for `api.evercam.io` does not match the hostname and therefore the certificate verification fails.
Same as true for `www.evercam.io`, e.g. try https://www.evercam.io with a browser and you get the error message, that the name in the certificate does not match the hostname.

So it is a problem which needs to be fixed by evercam.io. If you don't care about security, man-in-the-middle attacks etc you might disable verification of the certificate (`curl --insecure`), but then you should ask yourself why you use https instead of http at all.

Answer (score 6):

it might save some time to somebody.

If you use **GuzzleHttp** and you face with this error message *cURL error 60: SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name* and you are fine with the 'insecure' solution (not recommended on production) then you have to add
`\GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions::VERIFY => false` to the client configuration:

```
$this->client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([
    'base_uri'                          => 'someAccessPoint',
    \GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions::HEADERS => [
        'User-Agent' => 'some-special-agent',
    ],
    'defaults'                          => [
        \GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions::CONNECT_TIMEOUT => 5,
        \GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions::ALLOW_REDIRECTS => true,
    ],
    \GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions::VERIFY  => false,
]);
```

which sets `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` to 0 and `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` to false in the `CurlFactory::applyHandlerOptions()` method

```
$conf[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST] = 0;
$conf[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = false;
```

From the [GuzzleHttp documentation](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#verify)

> **verify**
>
> Describes the SSL certificate verification behavior of a request.
>
> - Set to true to enable SSL certificate verification and use the default CA bundle > provided by operating system.
> - Set to false to disable certificate verification (this is insecure!).
> - Set to a string to provide the path to a CA bundle to enable verification using a custom certificate.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. In my case I was using digitalocean and nginx. 
I have first setup a domain example.app and a subdomain dev.exemple.app in digitalocean.
Second,I purchased two ssl certificat from godaddy.
And finaly, I configured two domain in nginx to use those two ssl certificat with the following snipet

My example.app domain config

```
    server {
    listen 7000 default_server;
    listen [::]:7000 default_server;

     listen 443 ssl default_server;
     listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;

    root /srv/nodejs/echantillonnage1;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name echantillonnage.app;
    ssl_certificate /srv/nodejs/certificatSsl/widcardcertificate/echantillonnage.app.chained.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /srv/nodejs/certificatSsl/widcardcertificate/echantillonnage.app.key;

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8090;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
 }
```

My dev.example.app

```
   server {
    listen 7000 default_server;
    listen [::]:7000 default_server;

     listen 444 ssl default_server;
     listen [::]:444 ssl default_server;

    root /srv/nodejs/echantillonnage1;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name dev.echantillonnage.app;
    ssl_certificate /srv/nodejs/certificatSsl/dev/dev.echantillonnage.app.chained.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /srv/nodejs/certificatSsl/dev/dev.echantillonnage.app.key;

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8091;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
 }
```

When I was launching https://dev.echantillonnage.app , I was getting

```
    Fix CURL (51) SSL error: no alternative certificate subject name matches
```

My mistake was the two lines bellow

```
    listen 444 ssl default_server;
     listen [::]:444 ssl default_server;
```

I had to change this to:

```
     listen 443 ssl;
     listen [::]:443 ssl;
```

Comment: can you explain why the `default_server`statement is a problem here?
Do you have other config marked as default server?
I have this curl issue just on the same host, not with external connections.

Answer (score 0):

As the error code says, "no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name" - so there is an issue with the SSL certificate.

The certificate should include SAN, and only SAN will be used. Some browsers ignore the deprecated Common Name.

RFC 2818 clearly states 
  "If a subjectAltName extension of type dNSName is present, that MUST
   be used as the identity. Otherwise, the (most specific) Common Name
   field in the Subject field of the certificate MUST be used. Although
   the use of the Common Name is existing practice, it is deprecated and
   Certification Authorities are encouraged to use the dNSName instead."

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar but for the purpose of testing, I had added the main domain name to my `/etc/hosts` file and kept struggling with it. So make sure you check that file once as well.