# MailGun cURL error 51: SSL (Error with WordPress)

Tags: wordpress, mailgun

I'm trying to send my WordPress emails (including post notifications) using the MailGun mailer. I logged onto my WordPress website the other day and received this error message from MailGun:

Versions:

WordPress: 4.9.7
WordPress MS: No
PHP: 7.1.18
WP Mail SMTP: 1.3.3

Params:

Mailer: mailgun
Constants: No
Api Key / Domain: Yes

Debug:

> cURL error 51: SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'api.mailgun.net'

I contacted MailGun directly and received this reply:

> Tested this on our side but not able to reproduce the same error. Unfortunately, we can't assist troubleshoot local issues but want to refer to guidance from websites such as Stack OverFlow for more information on this error.

I am a novice when it comes to code but I want to fix this issue.

Comment: There are a [lot of posts about this error](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=curl%20no%20alternative%20certificate%20subject%20name%20matches%20target%20host%20name).

Comment: It looks like [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20842970/fix-curl-51-ssl-error-no-alternative-certificate-subject-name-matches/35705281#35705281) readers are encouraged to turn off certificate verification, which is not ideal. However, if you are a novice then debugging this sort of thing can be a pain, and turning off verification may be your best bet - you could try contacting your server ISP to see if their on-box certificates are out of date. Are you on shared hosting?