# curl --cacert error "curl: (60) SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name"

Tags: ssl, curl

`curl: (60) SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name`

I don't understand this error. If I supply a **CA** certificate (with `--cacert` option), it doesn't even have a subject alternative name. And if it had one, it wouldn't match the target host name (my server) for sure.

If I, on the other hand, supply my *server* certificate, signed with the **CA**, it says: `SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate.` (That I would expect, because my computer does not trust the CA by default and that's correct.)

When combining the PEM certificates in one file, I get the same errors.

Using option `--capath` set to the directory with both *server* and *CA* certificates it says: `curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate` again.

How do I make the trust check work?

(It worked when using a single self-signed server certificate.)

Comment: There's one edge case the error message does make sense: when using a self-signed certificate. That works (that was my previous setup) and I didn't see any errors that time

Comment: Maybe the problem is that my server doesn't send the chain of certificates, but only the server one. I'll try to add the CA certificate there

Comment: No, the problem's the same

Comment: I had similar problem:
"curl: (51) SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'myserver.something' "
 though it was in the SAN list.

I found out that when I use the first DNSName in the SAN it did work.

I don't know if it's a know issue, but looks like curl didn't check ALL the DNS names in the SAN in my case.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use wget. `--ca-certificate=path/to/PEM/ca/cert`

Answer (score 3):

There are two different and nearly unrelated things here.

For curl using OpenSSL, as yours is, the *root* cert (normally a CA) must be in the file specified by `--cacert`, OR alternatively in the `--capath` directory *using special filenames* that consist of an 8-hexit truncated hash of the canonicalized subject name plus dot and zero (or a small number if collision), OR in the defaults for either if not specified; unless (at least) one of these is present you get the 'unable to get local issuer' error;

AND, the *server* certificate sent by the server (which normally is NOT the CA cert) must contain, in SubjectAltName (SAN) extension if present and otherwise in Subject.CommonName (CN), a hostname that matches the hostname in the *URL* you try to access. If the server cert contains SAN extension but no entry in that extension matches the URL, you get the error in your title; see e.g. [Fix CURL (51) SSL error: no alternative certificate subject name matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20842970/fix-curl-51-ssl-error-no-alternative-certificate-subject-name-matches)

A self-signed server cert varies from the usual case because it acts as *both* the root cert *and* the server cert, so it must BOTH be in `--cacert` or `--capath` or their defaults (even though properly speaking it isn't a CA) AND contain SAN (or in its absence CN) that matches the URL.

PS: if you can't determine for certain what cert the server is sending (perhaps because the config is complicated, or not certain if it has been restarted or refreshed), use

```
 openssl s_client -connect $host:$port -servername $host 2>&1 | openssl x509 -noout -text 
 # if OpenSSL version 1.1.1 you can omit -servername $host
```

Comment: The self-signed server cert worked (used `--cacert`) as you write.

But when I switched to the self-signed ca (and used `--cacert` too), I got the error in my question title.

Comment: Your command output:
`X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                DNS:my.ip.addr.ess`

So it should work. Maybe it has a problem, when SAN is not a domain, but an IP addr? I don't have a domain, I use the address everywhere.

Comment: I had no problems on my iPhone, and switched to wget which works.